# Conditional color style : plotly go.Bar

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'd like add conditional styling to a plotly stacked bar plot. Specifically, the top bar of the stack would be conditional based on the x-axis values.

Here's my code:

```
# sample df
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2010 - Q3','2010 - Q4','2011 - Q1','2011 - Q2','2011 - Q3','2011 - Q4'],
                   'Rate' : ['11.4','12.2','14.4','15.5','10.1','13.1'],
                   'Rate1': ['2.1','2.3','1.9','1.6','2.5','1.1']
                 })


clrs = 'rgb(222,0,0)'


fig = go.Figure(

            data=[

                  go.Bar(
                        x=df['Date'],
                        y=df['Rate'],
                        name='Natural Level'
                        ),

                  go.Bar(
                        x=df['Date'],
                        y=df['Rate1']),
                        name='Change',
                        marker=dict(color=clrs)
                        )

                  ],

            layout=go.Layout(

                title='Measuring excess demand and supply in the market.',

                xaxis=dict(
                    tickangle=90,
                    tickfont=dict(family='Rockwell', color='crimson', size=14)
                ),

                yaxis=dict(
                    title='Rate',
                    showticklabels=True
                ),

                barmode='stack',

            )
        )
```

The `clrs` variable takes the color value conditional on the list of x axis values. i.e `clrs = rgb(222,0,0) if df['Date'] in lst else rgb(0,222,0)`.

where `lst` is list of x-axis values.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your df or a sample df? This will make your code reproducible so others can more easily help

Comment: Yes. Added in sample df.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Original method: you can create a `Color` column in your df based on your condition, then pass this column to the `color` parameter in `marker=dict(color=clrs)`.

EDIT: you can slice the dataframe based on whether the `Date` column is in lst, then add both parts of the dataframe separately uses traces, specifying the color for each trace. This isn't the prettiest solution and should be replaced by a loop if you have more than two colors, but hopefully gets the job done here.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

## sample df
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2010 - Q3','2010 - Q4','2011 - Q1','2011 - Q2','2011 - Q3','2011 - Q4'],
                   'Rate' : ['11.4','12.2','14.4','15.5','10.1','13.1'],
                   'Rate1': ['2.1','2.3','1.9','1.6','2.5','1.1']
                 })

## first and last bar are in lst
lst = ['2010 - Q3', '2011 - Q4']

## NOT NEEDED ##

## add a color column to the df, apply along row
## df['Color'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'rgb(222,0,0)' if x['Date'] in lst else 'rgb(0,222,0)', axis=1)
## clrs = 'rgb(222,0,0)'

fig = go.Figure(

            data=[

                  go.Bar(
                        x=df['Date'],
                        y=df['Rate'],
                        name='Natural Level'
                        ),

                  ],

            layout=go.Layout(

                title='Measuring excess demand and supply in the market.',

                xaxis=dict(
                    tickangle=90,
                    tickfont=dict(family='Rockwell', color='crimson', size=14)
                ),

                yaxis=dict(
                    title='Rate',
                    showticklabels=True
                ),

                barmode='stack',

            )
        ) 

## part of the dataframe in the lst
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
                        x=df[df['Date'].isin(lst)]['Date'],
                        y=df[df['Date'].isin(lst)]['Rate1'],
                        name='Change1',
                        marker=dict(color='rgb(222,0,0)')
                        )

    )
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
                        x=df[~df['Date'].isin(lst)]['Date'],
                        y=df[~df['Date'].isin(lst)]['Rate1'],
                        name='Change2',
                        marker=dict(color='rgb(0,222,0)')
                        )

    )

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This works. however, the legend doesn't change. how would you change the legend to display both colors?

Answer (score 3):

The basic form is how to create a list of colors for the x-axis, so there are many different approaches. I suggest this as an example of how to make a color list with conditions.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# sample df
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2010 - Q3','2010 - Q4','2011 - Q1','2011 - Q2','2011 - Q3','2011 - Q4'],
                   'Rate' : ['11.4','12.2','14.4','15.5','10.1','13.1'],
                   'Rate1': ['2.1','2.3','1.9','1.6','2.5','1.1']
                 })

clrs = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[i,'Date'][:4] == '2010':
        clrs.append('rgb(222,0,0)')
    else:
        clrs.append('rgb(0,100,0)')
#clrs = ['rgb(222,0,0)','rgb(222,0,0)','rgb(0,100,0)','rgb(0,100,0)','rgb(0,100,0)','rgb(0,100,0)']


fig = go.Figure(
            data=[
                  go.Bar(
                        x=df['Date'],
                        y=df['Rate'],
                        name='Natural Level'
                        ),
                  go.Bar(
                        x=df['Date'],
                        y=df['Rate1'],
                        name='Change',
                        marker=dict(color=clrs)
                        )
                  ],
            layout=go.Layout(
                title='Measuring excess demand and supply in the market.',
                xaxis=dict(
                    tickangle=90,
                    tickfont=dict(family='Rockwell', color='crimson', size=14)
                ),
                yaxis=dict(
                    title='Rate',
                    showticklabels=True
                ),
                barmode='stack',
            )
        )

fig.show()
```

[image]